# AWS Load Balancer / Target Group 443 Not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-application-load-balancer

I have a container that is exposing ports 443 and port 80. I created a task definition that exposes port 80 and port 443. I then created a target group for https and http. I setup a load balancer that is listening to HTTPS and HTTP for the target groups created. I then went and created a ECS service. The service loads the container port 443. It asked me to create a new target group but I just pointed at the https target group that I created previously. Once the service is running, I go to the alb url and I get a 503 Service Temporarily Unavailable. I looked at the access logs and it looks like the alb is forwarding to nowhere "forward" "-" "-" "-" "-" "-" "-"..

What's interesting is that if I go to the ip addresses of the container I can access both :80 and :443 with no problem at all. So obviously I am not doing something right with the load balancer.

Not sure how to resolve this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: 1. What are the target group health check settings? 2. Do you have an actual SSL certificate installed in the container? 3. Why deal with SSL at the container instead of doing SSL termination at the ALB?

Comment: I have a third party container that exposes an https port at 3000. I don't have any control over that. I have a self signed certificate that is stored in IAM with ELBSecurityPolicy-2016-08. 

When I create the service, under "Add Container to Load Balancer" I allow it to create a new target group name. When a new target group is created it is on port 80 instead of 443 I don't know if this matters. I do select Target group protocol "HTTPS" however.

Comment: "When a new target group is created it is on port 80 instead of 443" That sounds wrong. If the container is listening on port 3000 then the target group should be configured on port 3000. Also you didn't answer my question about the health check settings. Is the health check currently passing or failing?

Comment: I misspoke apologies. I changed the ports to 443 and 80. Total Targets 1. Healthy 0. Unhealthy 0. Unused 0. Initial 0. Draining 1

Comment: So your health check is failing. Without knowing more about this third-party docker image you are using it's difficult for anybody on here to provide you with any further help in that area.

Comment: Is there a way for me to determine why it is failing. I don't see anything in the logs. The third party docker image is running and fine. I can go to the ec2 ip and connect. It is only the target group that is causing the problem. Could you tell me where to look?

Comment: Maybe look in the logs of the service running in the Docker container? Or look at the target group settings (path, port, etc.) and try to make that same request yourself using something like `curl` to see why it isn't working.